# parameterized sql script using wrapper

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, parameter-passing, wrapper

I have created below sql script where i am trying to parameterized it using zone and market ans saved this script as wrapper.sql

```
define zone1= &1.
define market1= &2.
set lines etc
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET LIN 256
SET WRAP OFF
SET PAGES 0
spool H:\extract_&zone1&market1..csv
select 'zone'         ||','||
       'market'         ||','||
       'id'                 
result from dual
union all
select zone    ||','||
       market    ||','||
       id     
from solution_report
where rownum <5 and zone = &zone1 and market = &market1;
/
spool off
```

Now as i have 23 zones with respect to the market i have created 23 wrapper script and saved it in file `wrapper_script.sql`. I want to generate 23 excel files for each zone with respect to their market.

```
@C:\Users\raw\Desktop\wrapper.sql As Asia
.
.
.
@C:\Users\raw\Desktop\wrapper.sql AF Africa
```

But when i am trying to run this wrapper_script.sql then its generating the 23 csv files but there is no  data in the file. I am using oracle sql developer client to run this scripts as i dont have access to sql plus.

I am not sure whether i am using spool on the wrong place or i am calling it wrong as i am passing string values in wrapper?

Also is there any other way around so that instead of creating 23 wrapper files it can optimize the work.

Below is my select query result and i believe i have to format the string for zone and market column.

```
zone,market,boutique_id
EUR,Belgium,1233
EUR,Portugal,1345
EUR,Portugal,1567
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "creating 23 wrapper files"?  You have **one** SQL script called `wrapper.sql` that you run 23 times to create 23 CSV files - which I understand is what you want?

Comment: no i am not creating 23 wrapper files but i am calling it 23 times in wrapper_script.sql file so that it will create 23 csv files with different zones. And this i want to improve if it is possible that instead of calling 23 times is there any other way for example creating dynamic sql query

Comment: You could generate the outer script with code like `select '@C:\Users\raw\Desktop\wrapper.sql '||zone||' '||market from some_table;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&1.` and `&2.` in the script to reference the 1st and second command line parameters.  You can immediately assign them to named variables like this:

```
define zone1 = &1.
define market1 = &2.
```

The `.` at the end is optional but I prefer to always use it to avoid ambiguity in some cases.

Comment: its generating the file now but with .lst extension and i dont know the reson. And also there is no data in file

Comment: `.lst` is the default extension if you don't give one. And you haven't due to to not having a `.` at the end of the variable in `extract_&zone1&market1.csv` (this is what I meant about ambiguity): if zone1='xxx' then this becomes `extract_&zone1xxxcsv` that has no extension so Oracle adds the default.  Change the code to `extract_&zone1&market1..csv`.

Comment: I don't know why there is no data.

Comment: thanks its generating csv file now. But just small question when i run only the select query its returning the vaules. Do you have any idea abt i am using spool on the wrong place or i am calling it wrong as i am passing string values in wrapper?

Comment: I fthey are strings then you need to quote them: `zone = '&zone1.' and market = '&market1.'`

Comment: yes i have tried with quotes but still there is not data in csv files. Do i need to put quotes in wrapper file also where i am calling wrapper file ?